# Google Map in android adding dynamically

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using following code to add `map` in my android app inside a `fragment` navigated via `navigation drawer`. This is working fine in `android 5.0.0` and below version but it gives run time error when tried on micromax handset with android version 4.2.1

```
GoogleMap mMap;
SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
View view ;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapchkng, container, false);
    mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.map4, mMapFragment).commit();
    return view;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.dis, ""+e, 1).show();
        return view;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
super.onAttach(activity);
Log.d("Attach", "on attach");
}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
super.onDetach();
}
```

This is my xml file for layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/map4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
   android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    ></FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the error message in the logcat?